# Voting system using PHP+MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

We have to make a ballot system that makes users vote for various candidates on different positions. There's a login for voters. How do you store a vote of one voter and then get that vote added to the previous votes? The only possible way is to store every vote on a database right? But what would the structure of the database look like? And how do you count it?

edit:
The voting system doesnt only have one group of candidates to vote. It has mayor, vice-mayor, senator, etc. There are too many. that's why I'm confused. If only it was just a voting system of a president, it would be easier. So if I have a table for the voter, with a column of his/her voted candidate, it's not possible since the voter votes for many candidates.

Comment: But in an ideal voting system, you don't do that. You don't count 2 votes of single voter.. Either you replace the previous vote, or restrict him from voting twice..

Comment: @RohitJain There are different positions so a voter needs to vote for multiple candidates. Thats why it confuses me.

Comment: Well, then in that case you can have a separate table for Candidate Type(or Voting Position) according to your need.. And make `(VoterId, and CandidateType)` as composite Key in Votes Table..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to have a different table to store Votes. And that table will have two attributes (VoterId, CandidateId)
And you can fetch the Vote Count if you are allowing multiple votes from this table..

But it would be better to make VoterId a Primary key in this table.. To avoid multiple voting

> **CandidateType**: - (TypeId(PK), typeName, maxVotePerVoterForThisType)
>
> **Voter Table**: -  (voterId(PK), voterName, otherInfo)
>
> **Candidate Table**: -  (candidateId(PK), candidateName, constituency,
> otherInfo, TypeId(FK))
>
> **Votes**:- (voterId(PK, FK), TypeId(PK, FK), candidateId(FK))

*EDIT:- Schema edited with changed requirement in original post

*EDIT: - Added a field in CandidateType table to allow `multiple votes`.(E.g.: Now a voter can vote for `10 Senators`, if `maxVotePerVoter` for this type is set to 10..)

Comment: You're assuming that there is only one candidate that a voter will vote. In my case, there are a lot of candidates to vote for. One for mayor, vice-mayor, 15 for senators, etc.

Comment: @user1551672.. See updated schema, which will fit your requirement.. Now a Voter can vote for only one candidate of a particular type or in a particular position  (So, he can have 1 vote each for Mayor, Vice-MAyor, Senator...etc)

Comment: Or in the Votes table, you don't even need to store TypeId, that you can get from Candidate table also. But in that case you yourself have to manage duplicate votes.. By using SQL Query.

Comment: thank you. Will this work if in the senator position, the voter needs to vote for at least 10 candidates?

Comment: @user1551672.. No, if you have only one type for Senator position in your Candidate Type table.. But you can achieve it by adding an extra column to your CandidateType Table (maxVote), and while you add a Vote for a particular type and a particular voter, check for the maximum allowed vote per voter for this candidate from Type Table..

Comment: Change like this: - `**Candidate Type**:  -(typeId(PK), typeName, maxVotePerVoter)`   And set it 10 for Senator, and 1 for every one else..

Comment: Well in the senators, the voter needs to vote at least 12. Now I'm confused again. It's tricky if in one position, a voter can vote for more than 1.

Comment: @user1551672:  Well, I cannot understand to this requirement.. At least 12?? How are you going to handle it when a Voter votes for first time??

Comment: I know right. But in real life, you really have to vote for more than one in senator position cause.. thats just how politics work. Since it would be more hard if i follow the rules, I'll just do only one. At least I have a project to submit. 
Thanks. I haven't tried it but I'm currently working on it. I will ask again for your help if theres a problem.

Comment: @user1551672... Well you are mixing up your comments.. First you told that voter can voter upto 10 senators.. then you said he should vote for `at least` 12 senators.. Then again you are talking about more votes.. If your concern is about multiple votes for senator position, I have given the workaround, by using `maxVotePerVoter` in `CandidateType` table..

Comment: How would I make foreign key using phpmyadmin?

Comment: @user1551672 Aren't you getting an option to create one there?? You need to check it.. Although its been 4 years since I last used PHP, but as far as I remember there must be one..

Comment: I checked out my classmate's code. He already completed the voting system. He has a field of no of votes in the candidate table. It works now. It can vote and add the vote. But the problem is the login of the voter.

Comment: Well, what problem could you face with LOGIN??

Answer (score 1):

You should e store each candidate in a table, positions in another table then make relations based on ID, the voting system is relatively simple:

database:

```
id, position_id, candidate_id, votes
```

then PHP

```
$query = "UPDATE `votes` SET `votes`=`votes`+1 WHERE `position_id`=1 AND candidate_id=1"; // adds 1 vote where position_id is 1 and candidate_id is 1
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to race conditions and doesn't cover single-vote.

Comment: So I should make a table where all the candidates are listed. I have an html form of where the voter should vote. How do you add the users' votes on the database?

Comment: He can make another table with votes by every user to cover single votes

Comment: @user1551672 you either add another field in your database where the candidates are, or you add another table and store the votes there and count them .

Answer (score 1):

These 3 tables are required for your accounts (the voters) and candidates.

```
Account: Id (PK), Name, Password
Candidates: Id (PK), Name
Votes: AccountId (PK), CandidateId (PK)
```

Insert a row into votes when a vote is cast. This prevents duplicate voting due to the PK's.

Comment: The voting system doesnt only have one group of candidates to vote. It has mayor, vice-mayor, senator, etc. There are too many. that's why I'm confused. If only it was just a voting system of a president, it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation of problem, I can suggest you the following database structure:

tlbUserVote:

```
UserID(PK)  |  UserName  |  Vote  |  CandidateId(FK)
```

tlbCandidate:

```
CandidateId(PK)  | CandidateName | TotalVotes
```

By this structure you can add the current votes with previous ones (by taking previous votes first and adding it to the current).

Total votes of the candidates will get updated, too.

Comment: Like I said earlier,
The voting system doesnt only have one group of candidates to vote. It has mayor, vice-mayor, senator, etc. There are too many. that's why I'm confused. If only it was just a voting system of a president, it would be easier.

Comment: here in tlbCandidate table you can have any one as candidate....you just need to add Candidate type over here

Answer (score 0):

I simple language i can say you are storing voting users in a table called users and you can use a field `vaotecount`  (int) type initilize with zero and track their ip and vote for topic id on which they have voted for and when they vote you can check with IP and topic_id that they are not voting twice and if they passed you can increment the `vaotecount` field by one

and while you are counting for votes count the users with topic id  for which you counting votes. Simple :D