# MySQL Processing votes for a like/dislike system via AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a site which contains a voting system for its content. Because of this, I have set up a MySQL table called `votes` with columns for `uid`, `pid` and `value`, corresponding to the UUID of the user voting, the text-based ID of the post and the boolean value of the vote (`0` or `1` for dislike and like).

I've seen several similar questions about this, although none seem to refer directly to inserting and manipulating votes in communication between PHP and a MySQL database. Most seem to refer to [database structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550995/voting-system-using-phpmysql) or [SELECTing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224301/vote-system-php-mysql). None that I could find seemed to mimic the system I would like to end up with.

The database and PHP which interacts with it works fine - I have certain pages set up which generate JSON containing the amount of each type of vote and the personal vote of the given user, for that post.  The issue I have had is in optimising the process of users inputting their votes - the 'rules' I am looking for when voting is the following:

- If the exact vote being inputted already exists (i.e. given `uid`, `pid` and `value` all exist as an identical record), remove the vote from the table;
- If there is currently no vote on this post and by this user, add a vote to the table with all three values;
- If there is a vote by this user on this post, but it is opposite (dislike rather than like, or vice versa), update the record so that the vote matches.

The page receives `$currentUid` through a session variable, and both `$cid` and `$_GET["v"]` (obviously) through GET parameters.

I have been able to produce this behaviour in PHP with the use of PDO in two MySQL calls (assume `$con` to be a generic PDO object):

```
$test = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE uid=UNHEX(:uid) AND pid=:pid AND value=:value");
$test->bindValue(":uid", $currentUid);
$test->bindValue(":pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$test->bindValue(":value", $_GET["v"], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$test->execute();

if($test->rowCount() > 0) {
    $query = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM `votes` WHERE uid=UNHEX(:uid) AND pid=:pid AND value=:value LIMIT 1");
    $query->bindValue(":uid", $currentUid);
    $query->bindValue(":pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(":value", $_GET["v"], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
    $query->execute();
} else {
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `votes` (uid, pid, value) VALUES (UNHEX(:uid), :pid, :value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = :value");
    $query->bindValue(":uid", $currentUid);
    $query->bindValue(":pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(":value", $_GET["v"], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the same effect with just one larger MySQL call, and will it affect the performance of the system in any way? I've found in the past that using longer MySQL statements can take longer than simply working out a solution with a mixture of PHP and MySQL. It can be assumed that the system will be handling votes often, so performance is important here.

At the moment this process takes about 0.05 of a second (through simple `microtime()` benchmarks), which would definitely add up given several concurrent users.

Thank you for your help! Take note I'm not an expert in SQL syntax, I've just learned how to perform an `INNER JOIN` - which is why I've decided to post here, as if there is some MySQL function which does exactly this I would have trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem quite possible to do the same in one mysql call.

As a first step, remove the SELECT query unless you absolutely need it for later use. You ON DUPLICATE KEY statement will do that for you.

The DELETE is however necessary. There is no ON DUPLICATE KEY DELETE syntax.

You can however write a TRIGGER that works on AFTER INSERT and removes duplicates if any. Its a crude approach but it will take the load off of PHP. Do this if you are absolutely adamant to do the task in a SINGLE query

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on table `votes` set to `(uid, pid)` then `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is all you need... *if* you'll consider using a ternary `ENUM` -- +1, 0, -1 -- in `value` for "like", "no opinion", and "dislike" appropriately.

In the case of no votes existing for a given `(uid, pid)` combination, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will insert the provided value. If a vote exists and the user wishes to retract a down-vote (from -1 to 0), retract an up-vote (1 to 0) or apply a down-vote or up-vote (0 to 1 or -1), `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will update the record instead.

With this approach, the only reason to delete the vote is on a cascading operation, such as deleting the post or the user records. I'll bet you probably have some application code that translates Boolean TRUE to Integer +1 and Boolean FALSE to -1 anyway. As a bonus, recording a 0 vote also provides the information about whether that user has voted on that post previously, even if they have since retracted their up- or down-vote.

As a final consideration, you should wrap your vote change operation in a transaction and over-qualify the row you want to `UPDATE` to prevent collision with the user's *next* action, which might get processed *out of order* because of... well, internet.

Comment: Would it be worth the added space within the database to implement this (for extra records), and furthermore would it drastically increase performance? I have no wish to log whether or not a user has voted in the past.

Comment: MySQL is quite efficient with `ENUM`, so not much size or performance loss there. Consider a vacuum task to clean up 0-value vote records: `DELETE FROM votes WHERE created_on > yesterday AND value = 0`